# Optimization problem with gekko in a bioreactor system

Tags: gekko

I am trying to Optimize this Biochemical System using the loading profile as a manipulated variable (Qin) in order to produce the desired concentration of the product P (`P*final>=70.5`) without waste of S (`S*final<=0`) while being time efficient (MINIMIZE tf), for large scale (V=2000000 L). I started using some examples of `gekko` and modifying the basic script of the reactor in order to apply in larger scale production. I tried different techniques that I found here but I still couldn't manage to make it converge.

Here is my basic script:

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

m = GEKKO() # initialize GEKKO
nt = 501
m.time = np.linspace(0,1,nt)

# Define constants and parameters
#################################
# Kinetic Parameters
a1     = m.Const(value=0.05, name='a1')     # Ratkowsky parameter [oC-1 h-0.5]
aP     = m.Const(value=4.50, name='aP')     # Growth-associated parameter for EtOh production [-]
AP1    = m.Const(value=6.0, name='AP1')     # Activation energy parameter for EtOh production [oC]
AP2    = m.Const(value=20.3, name='AP2')    # Activation energy parameter for EtOh production [oC]
b1     = m.Const(value=0.035, name='b1')    # Parameter in the exponential expression of the maximum specific growth rate expression [oC-1]
b2     = m.Const(value=0.15, name='b2')     # Parameter in the exponential expression of the maximum specific growth rate expression [oC-1]
b3     = m.Const(value=0.40, name='b3')     # Parameter in the exponential expression of the specific death rate expression [oC-1]
c1     = m.Const(value=0.38, name='c1')     # Constant decoupling factor for EtOh [gP gX-1 h-1]
c2     = m.Const(value=0.29, name='c2')     # Constant decoupling factor for EtOh [gP gX-1 h-1]
k1     = m.Const(value=3, name='k1')        # Parameter in the maximum specific growth rate expression [oC]
k2     = m.Const(value=55, name='k2')       # Parameter in the maximum specific growth rate expression [oC]
k3     = m.Const(value=60, name='k3')       # Parameter in the growth-inhibitory EtOH concentration expression [oC]
k4     = m.Const(value=50, name='k4')       # Temperature at the inflection point of the specific death rate sigmoid curve [oC]
Pmaxb  = m.Const(value=90, name='Pmaxb')    # Temperature-independent product inhibition constant [g L-1]
PmaxT  = m.Const(value=90, name='PmaxT')    # Maximum value of product inhibition constant due to temperature [g L-1]
Kdb    = m.Const(value=0.025, name='Kdb')   # Basal specific cellular biomass death rate [h-1]
KdT    = m.Const(value=30, name='KdT')      # Maximum value of specific cellular biomass death rate due to temperature [h-1]
KSX    = m.Const(value=5, name='KSX')       # Glucose saturation constant for the specific growth rate [g L-1]
KOX    = m.Const(value=0.0005, name='KOX')  # Oxygen saturation constant for the specific growth rate [g L-1]
qOmax  = m.Const(value=0.05, name='qOmax')  # Maximum specific oxygen consumption rate [h-1]

# Metabolic Parameters
YPS    = m.Const(value=0.51, name='YPS')    # Theoretical yield of EtOH on glucose [gP gS-1]
YXO    = m.Const(value=0.97, name='YXO')    # Theoretical yield of biomass on oxygen [gX gO-1]
YXS    = m.Const(value=0.53, name='YXS')    # Theoretical yield of biomass on glucose [gX gS-1]

# Physicochemical and thermodynamic parameters
Chbr   = m.Const(value=4.18, name='Chbr')      # Heat capacity of the mass of reaction [J g-1 oC-1]
Chc    = m.Const(value=4.18, name='Chc')       # Heat capacity of cooling agent [J g-1 oC-1]
deltaH = m.Const(value=518000, name='deltaH')  # Heat of reaction of fermentation [J mol-1 O2]
Tref   = m.Const(value=25, name='Tref')        # Reference temperature [oC]
KH     = m.Const(value=200, name='KH')         # Henry's constant for oxygen in the fermentation broth [atm L mol-1]
z      = m.Const(value=0.792, name='z')        # Oxygen compressibility factor [-]
R      = m.Const(value=0.082, name='R')        # Ideal gas constant [L atm mol-1 oC-1]
kla0   = m.Const(value=100, name='kla0')       # Temperature-independent volumetric oxygen transfer coefficient [-h]
KT     = m.Const(value=360000, name='KT')      # Heat transfer coefficient [J h-1 m-2 oC-1]
rho    = m.Const(value=1080, name='rho')       # Density of the fermentation broth [g L-1]
rhoc   = m.Const(value=1000, name='rhoc')      # Density of the cooling agent [g L-1]
MO     = m.Const(value=32.0, name='MO')        # Molecular weight of oxygen [g mol-1]

# Bioreactor design data
AT     = m.FV(lb=1.0, name='AT')         # Bioreactor heat transfer area [m2]
AT.STATUS =1
V      = m.Const(value=2000000, name='V')        # Bioreactor working volume [L]
Vcj    = m.FV(lb= 50, name='Vcj')       # Cooling jacket volume [L]
Vcj.STATUS = 1
Ogasin = m.Const(value=0.305, name='Ogasin')  # Oxygen concentration in airflow inlet [g L-1]

# Define variables
##################
mi = m.Var(name='mi',lb=0)

# Trying Const. instead of FV which Fixed variables, they are constant throughout the time horizon
Xtin = m.Const(value=0, name='Xtin')
Xvin = m.Const(value=0, name='Xvin')
Qe   = m.Const(value=0, name='Qe')
Si  = m.Const(value=200, name='Si')
Pin  = m.Const(value=0, name='Pin')
Fc   = m.FV(lb=40.0, name='Fc')
Fc.STATUS = 1
Fair = m.Const(value=6000000.0, name='Fair')
Tin  = m.Const(value=30, name='Tin')
Tcin = m.Const(value=15, name='Tcin')

Vl     = m.Var(value=500000, name='Vl')  #lb=-0.0, ub=0.75*V
Xt     = m.Var(value=0.1, name='Xt') # lb=-0.0, ub=10
Xv     = m.Var(value=0.1, name='Xv') # lb=-0.0, ub=10
S      = m.Var(value=75, name='S')   # lb=+0.0, ub=10000
P      = m.Var(value=0, name='P')
Ol     = m.Var(value=0.0065, name= 'Ol')
Og     = m.Var(value=0.305, name='Og')
T      = m.Var(value=30, name='T')    # lb=20, ub=40
Tc     = m.Var(value=20, name='Tc')   # lb=0, ub=30
#Sf_cum = m.Var(value=0, name='Sf_cum')
#t      = m.Var(value=0, name='Time')

p = np.zeros(nt) # final time = 1
p[-1] = 1.0
final = m.Param(value=p)
# optimize final time
tf = m.FV(value=20.0,lb=0.1,ub=100.0)
tf.STATUS = 1
# control changes every time period
Qin = m.MV(value=0,lb=0.0,ub=1000000, name= 'Qin')
Qin.STATUS = 1

############################
# Specific growth rate of cell mass
mimax = m.Intermediate(((a1*(T-k1))*(1-m.exp(b1*(T-k2))))** 2)
Pmax = m.Intermediate(Pmaxb + PmaxT/(1-m.exp(-b2*(T-k3))))
m.Equation(mi == mimax * (S / (KSX+S)) * (Ol/(KOX + Ol)) \
                 * (1 - P/Pmax) * (1 / (1+m.exp(-(100-S)))))
#mi = m.if3(condition=mi, x1=0, x2=mi)
# Specific production rate of EtOH
#bP = m.if3(condition=S, x1=0, x2=c1*m.exp(-AP1/T) - c2*m.exp(-AP2/T))
bP = m.Intermediate(c1*m.exp(-AP1/T) - c2*m.exp(-AP2/T))
qP = m.Intermediate(aP*mi + bP)
# Specific consumption rate of glucose
qS = m.Intermediate(mi/YXS + qP/YPS)
# Specific consumption rate of oxygen
qO = m.Intermediate(qOmax*Ol/YXO/(KOX+Ol))
# Specific biological deactivation rate of cell mass
Kd = m.Intermediate(Kdb + KdT/(1+m.exp(-b3*(T-k4))))
# Saturation concentration of oxygen in culture media
Ostar = m.Intermediate(z*Og*R*T/KH)
# Oxygen mass transfer coefficient
kla = m.Intermediate(kla0*1.2**(T-20))
# Bioreactor phases equation
Vg = m.Intermediate(V - Vl)

# Define differential equations
###############################
m.Equation(Vl.dt()     == (Qin - Qe)*tf)
m.Equation(Vl*Xt.dt()  == (Qin*(Xtin-Xt) + mi*Vl*Xv)*tf)
m.Equation(Vl*Xv.dt()  == (Qin*(Xvin-Xv) + Xv*Vl*(mi-Kd))*tf)
m.Equation(Vl*S.dt()   == (Qin*(Si-S) - qS*Vl*Xv)*tf)
m.Equation(Vl*P.dt()   == (Qin*(Pin - P) + qP*Vl*Xv)*tf)
m.Equation(Vl*Ol.dt()  == (Qin*(Ostar-Ol)   + Vl*kla*(Ostar-Ol) - qO*Vl*Xv)*tf)
m.Equation(Vg*Og.dt()  == (Fair*(Ogasin-Og) - Vl*kla*(Ostar-Ol) + Og*(Qin-Qe))*tf)
m.Equation(Vl*T.dt()   == (Qin*(Tin-T) - Tref*(Qin-Qe) \
                          + Vl*qO*Xv*deltaH/MO/rho/Chbr - KT*AT*(T-Tc)/rho/Chbr)*tf)
m.Equation(Vcj*Tc.dt() == (Fc*(Tcin - Tc) + KT*AT*(T-Tc)/rhoc/Chc)*tf)
#m.Equation(Sf_cum.dt() == Qin*Sin)
#

#m.options.OTOL = 0.001
#m.options.RTOL = 0.001
#m.options.MAX_ITER = 300
#m.open_folder()
#m.options.SOLVER = 1
#m.options.IMODE=7
#m.solve()

m.Equation(Vl*final<=1500000)
m.Equation(S*final==0)
m.Equation(P*final==70.5*final)
m.Obj(tf)

m.options.SOLVER = 1
m.options.IMODE = 6

m.solve(disp= True)

print('Final Time: ' + str(tf.value[0]))
tm = np.linspace(0,tf.value[0],nt)
plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(tm,Vl.value,'k-',label=r'$x_1$')
plt.plot(tm,S.value,'b-',label=r'$x_2$')
plt.plot(tm,P.value,'g--',label=r'$x_3$')
plt.plot(tm,Qin.value,'r--',label=r'$u$')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

The terminal constraints and `mi<0` are causing the solution to not converge. Try separating the problem into two (or more) phases. The first phase adds a slack variable for `mi`

```py
mi_slk = m.Var(lb=0)
m.Minimize(mi_slk)
m.Equation(mi == mimax * (S / (KSX+S)) * (Ol/(KOX + Ol)) \
                 * (1 - P/Pmax) * (1 / (1+m.exp(-(100-S))))+mi_slk)
```

and solves successfully without the terminal constraints.

```py
Fc.STATUS = 1
AT.STATUS =1
Vcj.STATUS = 1
tf.STATUS = 1
Qin.STATUS = 1
m.Minimize(tf)
m.Equation(Vl*final<=1500000)
m.options.SOLVER = 1
m.options.IMODE = 6
m.solve(disp= True)
```

Here is the solution to phase 1:

```
 Iter    Objective  Convergence
   50  1.02000E+01  5.76159E-01
   51  1.00000E+01  9.19157E-01
   52  1.00000E+01  9.04511E-04
   53  1.00000E+01  6.28992E-09
   54  1.00000E+01  6.28992E-09
 Successful solution
 
 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  APOPT (v1.0)
 Solution time  :  14.7956 sec
 Objective      :  9.99999999999998
 Successful solution
 ---------------------------------------------------
```

The second phase has the terminal constraints:

```py
# hard constraints
m.Equation(S*final==0)
m.Equation(P*final==70.5*final)
# soft constraints (objective form)
m.Minimize(final*1e-3*S**2)
m.Minimize(final*1e-3*(P-70.5)**2)
```

Timepoints are reduced to `101` during the development of the application. The timepoints can be increased to `501` once a successful solution is found and a high-resolution result is desired.

```py
nt = 101
m.time = np.linspace(0,1,nt)
```

Here is the complete script:

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

m = GEKKO(remote=False) # initialize GEKKO
nt = 101
m.time = np.linspace(0,1,nt)

# Define constants and parameters
#################################
# Kinetic Parameters
a1     = m.Const(value=0.05, name='a1')     # Ratkowsky parameter [oC-1 h-0.5]
aP     = m.Const(value=4.50, name='aP')     # Growth-associated parameter for EtOh production [-]
AP1    = m.Const(value=6.0, name='AP1')     # Activation energy parameter for EtOh production [oC]
AP2    = m.Const(value=20.3, name='AP2')    # Activation energy parameter for EtOh production [oC]
b1     = m.Const(value=0.035, name='b1')    # Parameter in the exponential expression of the maximum specific growth rate expression [oC-1]
b2     = m.Const(value=0.15, name='b2')     # Parameter in the exponential expression of the maximum specific growth rate expression [oC-1]
b3     = m.Const(value=0.40, name='b3')     # Parameter in the exponential expression of the specific death rate expression [oC-1]
c1     = m.Const(value=0.38, name='c1')     # Constant decoupling factor for EtOh [gP gX-1 h-1]
c2     = m.Const(value=0.29, name='c2')     # Constant decoupling factor for EtOh [gP gX-1 h-1]
k1     = m.Const(value=3, name='k1')        # Parameter in the maximum specific growth rate expression [oC]
k2     = m.Const(value=55, name='k2')       # Parameter in the maximum specific growth rate expression [oC]
k3     = m.Const(value=60, name='k3')       # Parameter in the growth-inhibitory EtOH concentration expression [oC]
k4     = m.Const(value=50, name='k4')       # Temperature at the inflection point of the specific death rate sigmoid curve [oC]
Pmaxb  = m.Const(value=90, name='Pmaxb')    # Temperature-independent product inhibition constant [g L-1]
PmaxT  = m.Const(value=90, name='PmaxT')    # Maximum value of product inhibition constant due to temperature [g L-1]
Kdb    = m.Const(value=0.025, name='Kdb')   # Basal specific cellular biomass death rate [h-1]
KdT    = m.Const(value=30, name='KdT')      # Maximum value of specific cellular biomass death rate due to temperature [h-1]
KSX    = m.Const(value=5, name='KSX')       # Glucose saturation constant for the specific growth rate [g L-1]
KOX    = m.Const(value=0.0005, name='KOX')  # Oxygen saturation constant for the specific growth rate [g L-1]
qOmax  = m.Const(value=0.05, name='qOmax')  # Maximum specific oxygen consumption rate [h-1]

# Metabolic Parameters
YPS    = m.Const(value=0.51, name='YPS')    # Theoretical yield of EtOH on glucose [gP gS-1]
YXO    = m.Const(value=0.97, name='YXO')    # Theoretical yield of biomass on oxygen [gX gO-1]
YXS    = m.Const(value=0.53, name='YXS')    # Theoretical yield of biomass on glucose [gX gS-1]

# Physicochemical and thermodynamic parameters
Chbr   = m.Const(value=4.18, name='Chbr')      # Heat capacity of the mass of reaction [J g-1 oC-1]
Chc    = m.Const(value=4.18, name='Chc')       # Heat capacity of cooling agent [J g-1 oC-1]
deltaH = m.Const(value=518000, name='deltaH')  # Heat of reaction of fermentation [J mol-1 O2]
Tref   = m.Const(value=25, name='Tref')        # Reference temperature [oC]
KH     = m.Const(value=200, name='KH')         # Henry's constant for oxygen in the fermentation broth [atm L mol-1]
z      = m.Const(value=0.792, name='z')        # Oxygen compressibility factor [-]
R      = m.Const(value=0.082, name='R')        # Ideal gas constant [L atm mol-1 oC-1]
kla0   = m.Const(value=100, name='kla0')       # Temperature-independent volumetric oxygen transfer coefficient [-h]
KT     = m.Const(value=360000, name='KT')      # Heat transfer coefficient [J h-1 m-2 oC-1]
rho    = m.Const(value=1080, name='rho')       # Density of the fermentation broth [g L-1]
rhoc   = m.Const(value=1000, name='rhoc')      # Density of the cooling agent [g L-1]
MO     = m.Const(value=32.0, name='MO')        # Molecular weight of oxygen [g mol-1]

# Bioreactor design data
AT     = m.FV(lb=1.0, name='AT')         # Bioreactor heat transfer area [m2]
V      = m.Const(value=2000000, name='V')        # Bioreactor working volume [L]
Vcj    = m.FV(lb= 50, name='Vcj')       # Cooling jacket volume [L]
Ogasin = m.Const(value=0.305, name='Ogasin')  # Oxygen concentration in airflow inlet [g L-1]

# Define variables
##################
mi = m.Var(name='mi',lb=0)

# Trying Const. instead of FV which Fixed variables, they are constant throughout the time horizon
Xtin = m.Const(value=0, name='Xtin')
Xvin = m.Const(value=0, name='Xvin')
Qe   = m.Const(value=0, name='Qe')
Si  = m.Const(value=200, name='Si')
Pin  = m.Const(value=0, name='Pin')
Fc   = m.FV(lb=40.0, name='Fc')
Fair = m.Const(value=6000000.0, name='Fair')
Tin  = m.Const(value=30, name='Tin')
Tcin = m.Const(value=15, name='Tcin')

Vl     = m.Var(value=500000, name='Vl')  #lb=-0.0, ub=0.75*V
Xt     = m.Var(value=0.1, name='Xt') # lb=-0.0, ub=10
Xv     = m.Var(value=0.1, name='Xv') # lb=-0.0, ub=10
S      = m.Var(value=75, name='S')   # lb=+0.0, ub=10000
P      = m.Var(value=0, name='P')
Ol     = m.Var(value=0.0065, name= 'Ol')
Og     = m.Var(value=0.305, name='Og')
T      = m.Var(value=30, name='T')    # lb=20, ub=40
Tc     = m.Var(value=20, name='Tc')   # lb=0, ub=30
#Sf_cum = m.Var(value=0, name='Sf_cum')
#t      = m.Var(value=0, name='Time')

p = np.zeros(nt) # final time = 1
p[-1] = 1.0
final = m.Param(value=p)
# optimize final time
tf = m.FV(value=20.0,lb=0.1,ub=100.0)
# control changes every time period
Qin = m.MV(value=0,lb=0.0,ub=1000000, name= 'Qin')

############################
# Specific growth rate of cell mass
mimax = m.Intermediate(((a1*(T-k1))*(1-m.exp(b1*(T-k2))))** 2)
Pmax = m.Intermediate(Pmaxb + PmaxT/(1-m.exp(-b2*(T-k3))))
mi_slk = m.Var(lb=0)
m.Minimize(mi_slk)
m.Equation(mi == mimax * (S / (KSX+S)) * (Ol/(KOX + Ol)) \
                 * (1 - P/Pmax) * (1 / (1+m.exp(-(100-S))))+mi_slk)
#mi = m.if3(condition=mi, x1=0, x2=mi)
# Specific production rate of EtOH
#bP = m.if3(condition=S, x1=0, x2=c1*m.exp(-AP1/T) - c2*m.exp(-AP2/T))
bP = m.Intermediate(c1*m.exp(-AP1/T) - c2*m.exp(-AP2/T))
qP = m.Intermediate(aP*mi + bP)
# Specific consumption rate of glucose
qS = m.Intermediate(mi/YXS + qP/YPS)
# Specific consumption rate of oxygen
qO = m.Intermediate(qOmax*Ol/YXO/(KOX+Ol))
# Specific biological deactivation rate of cell mass
Kd = m.Intermediate(Kdb + KdT/(1+m.exp(-b3*(T-k4))))
# Saturation concentration of oxygen in culture media
Ostar = m.Intermediate(z*Og*R*T/KH)
# Oxygen mass transfer coefficient
kla = m.Intermediate(kla0*1.2**(T-20))
# Bioreactor phases equation
Vg = m.Intermediate(V - Vl)

# Define differential equations
###############################
m.Equation(Vl.dt()     == (Qin - Qe)*tf)
m.Equation(Vl*Xt.dt()  == (Qin*(Xtin-Xt) + mi*Vl*Xv)*tf)
m.Equation(Vl*Xv.dt()  == (Qin*(Xvin-Xv) + Xv*Vl*(mi-Kd))*tf)
m.Equation(Vl*S.dt()   == (Qin*(Si-S) - qS*Vl*Xv)*tf)
m.Equation(Vl*P.dt()   == (Qin*(Pin - P) + qP*Vl*Xv)*tf)
m.Equation(Vl*Ol.dt()  == (Qin*(Ostar-Ol)   + Vl*kla*(Ostar-Ol) - qO*Vl*Xv)*tf)
m.Equation(Vg*Og.dt()  == (Fair*(Ogasin-Og) - Vl*kla*(Ostar-Ol) + Og*(Qin-Qe))*tf)
m.Equation(Vl*T.dt()   == (Qin*(Tin-T) - Tref*(Qin-Qe) \
                          + Vl*qO*Xv*deltaH/MO/rho/Chbr - KT*AT*(T-Tc)/rho/Chbr)*tf)
m.Equation(Vcj*Tc.dt() == (Fc*(Tcin - Tc) + KT*AT*(T-Tc)/rhoc/Chc)*tf)

Fc.STATUS = 1
AT.STATUS =1
Vcj.STATUS = 1
tf.STATUS = 1
Qin.STATUS = 1
m.Minimize(tf)
m.Equation(Vl*final<=1500000)
m.options.SOLVER = 1
m.options.IMODE = 6
m.solve(disp= True)

# hard constraints
m.Equation(S*final==0)
m.Equation(P*final==70.5*final)
# soft constraints (objective form)
m.Minimize(final*1e-3*S**2)
m.Minimize(final*1e-3*(P-70.5)**2)

m.options.TIME_SHIFT = 0
m.solve(disp= True)

print('Final Time: ' + str(tf.value[0]))
tm = np.linspace(0,tf.value[0],nt)
plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(tm,Vl.value,'k-',label=r'$x_1$')
plt.plot(tm,S.value,'b-',label=r'$x_2$')
plt.plot(tm,P.value,'g--',label=r'$x_3$')
plt.plot(tm,Qin.value,'r--',label=r'$u$')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.show()
```

The second phase still hasn't solved yet. Perhaps the terminal constraints cannot be satisfied? It may also be worthwhile to check on the equation for `mi` to see if it should be a negative value.

Comment: Thank you a lot sir.  I'll work on the terminal constraints and the possibility at least one of them to be satisfied.  Thank you!

Comment: Also I know that there is at least one solution that satisfies both because I was able to satisfy them in MATLAB at the exact same model, through trial and error.  Do you think that it would be a good idea to set it as an initial guess?

Comment: It is a good idea to simulate a solution as an initial guess. Try setting the inputs to the simulation that you'd like to repeat. It will generally calculate those outputs for you so that it creates a better initial guess for the next solve.